# How to check string contain a year sarting from 20.. or 19

Tags: java, string, pattern-matching

I have a string, I want to check whether that string contain string like bellow, and get that string no(eg:2012) if exist. (I am trying to get years of a string)

```
"from 20##" , "From 20##" , "from 19##" or "From 19##"
```

and

```
  "to 20##" , "To 20##" , "to 19##" or "To 19##"    # can be any one digit no
```

please tell me how to do this

Comment: I can feel a regular expression coming on. ;)

Comment: @Roshanck well, let's start at the top - what **do** you know how to do with strings?  Could you, for instance, check whether the first character of a string was `'f'`?  You should be able to come up with at least an inefficient and inflexible solution to this...

Answer (score 0):

Use **Regular Expression** to search the pattern.

You can replace any digit by "`[/d]`" in the regular expression.

So, if you are searching for `20##`, your search pattern will be `20[\d][\d]`.

Have a look at [this tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/articles/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html) is you still have doubts.

Answer (score 0):

All you really need is

```
int year = Integer.parseInt(str.substring(str.length()-4)
```

and you are free to check that `year >= 1900 && year < 2100`.

If you need to assert that the string matches your pattern, you can test for

```
str.matches("([Ff]rom|[Tt]o)\\s+\\d{4}")
```